# ruby - how to generate the possible sequential combination of letters from an array of strings?

Tags: ruby, arrays, tuples, combinations

I have an array of strings:

```
["ABC", "GHI"]
```

ad I want all the 'letter' combinations, as reads from left to right, i.e.

```
["AG", "AH", "AI", "BG", "BH", "BI", "CG", "CH", "CI"]
```

but not

```
"GA", "GB", "HA", etc.
```

Similarly,

```
["ABC", "DEF", "GHI"]
```

should generate

```
["ADG", "ADH", "ADI", "AEG", "AEH", "AEI", "AFG", "AFH", "AFI", "BDG", "BDH", 
"BDI", "BEG", "BEH", "BEI", "BFG", "BFH", "BFI", "CDG", "CDH", "CDI", "CEG", 
"CEH", "CEI", "CFG", "CFH" "CFI"]
```

but not

```
"DAG", "GAD" or "GFA"
```

Comment: It is not clear what rule the array you specify follows. Also, you wrote you want combinations, but that seems to contradict that you want `"AG"` but not `"GA"`. The question is not clear.

Comment: _sequential_ combinations please :)

Comment: @sawa has a point. It's also not clear what dictates the length of the combination. Do you only want combinations the length of the array of strings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
a = ["ABC","DEF", "GHI"]
a.map(&:chars).reduce(&:product).map(&:join)
```

By the way, you made some errors in your example output, there should never be strings starting with an E or an F according to your specification. So I suppose instead of `"ECH", "ECI", "FCG", "FCH", "FCI"` you meant `"CEH", "CEI", "CFG", "CFH", "CFI"`.

**Edit:**

`chars` returns an Enumerator, not an array, and in Ruby versions before 2.0 those don't have a `product` method. So in those versions, just use a `to_a` like this:

```
a.map(&:chars).map(&:to_a).reduce(&:product).map(&:join)
```

Comment: In this case, why would you use `flat_map` over simply `map`?

Comment: That was a mistake, edited that out in the meantime. Actually `flat_map` will work too, it's just not needed.

Comment: Ok, cool. I was curious and learned what `:product` and `:flat_map` do. Didn't realize I could do that. Cheers!

Comment: This works, but I think there should be a more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: Efficient by what measure? This is an easy to read, easy to understand short line of code that takes a programmer 5 seconds to write. You never stated anything else in your question than the required output. Please accept my answer as this indeed works, and submit a new one with your specific needs if you have some.

Comment: Sorry, got confused for a moment. Leaving my comment there now anyway.

Comment: Thanks Arup.  btw I also corrected my required output as ggPeti noticed.

Comment: found that :product is only available in ruby 2+  Is there a 1.9 alternative?

Comment: It's _not_ 2+. See it here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-product (Also I just tried it on 1.8.7 and it worked.)

Comment: Oh I know what's the problem. Updating my answer.

Comment: One note product is available from 1.8.7 ruby http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html#method-i-product

Comment: I love seeing `reduce` used that way.  Perhaps replace the two successive maps with `a.map {|e| e.split('')}`.

Answer (score 4):

```
a = ["ABC","DEF", "GHI"]
first, *rest = a.map{|s| s.each_char.to_a}
first.product(*rest).map(&:join)
# =>
# ["ADG", "ADH", "ADI", "AEG", "AEH", "AEI", "AFG", "AFH", "AFI", "BDG", "BDH", "BDI",
# "BEG", "BEH", "BEI", "BFG", "BFH", "BFI", "CDG", "CDH", "CDI", "CEG", "CEH", "CEI",
# "CFG", "CFH", "CFI"]
```

Benchmarks comparing with @ggPeti’s solution:

```
t = Time.now
50000.times do
  a.map(&:chars).reduce(&:product).map(&:join)
end
puts Time.now - t
# => 2.037303374

t = Time.now
50000.times do
  first, *rest = a.map{|s| s.each_char.to_a}
  first.product(*rest).map(&:join)
end
puts Time.now - t
# => 1.670047516
```

Comment: I just started to write something like this.. Why not using `#split` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit You mean instead of `each_char`? That is more indirect way of doing it.

Comment: I mean instead of `s.each_char.to_a`, `s.split` ? Isn't good ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit `"ABC".split #=> ["ABC"]` `"ABC".split("") #=> ["A", "B", "C"]`

Comment: @ArupRakshit The intent here is to extract a character, not to extract a sequence that is surrounded by empty strings. The results are the same, but the latter is indirect.

Comment: @sawa then how `s.scan(/./)` would be ? If it work, then you don't need to type - `s.each_char.to_a`.. :-)

Comment: @ArupRakshit I am not doing code golf. I prioritize conceptual simplicity over decreasing the number of characters I have to type.

Comment: Btw, using `map(&:chars)` is ~10% faster than `map { |s| s.each_char.to_a }` in my benchmarking.

Answer (score 1):

A recursive solution:

```
def doit(b)
  recurse(b.map(&:chars))
end

def recurse(a)
  (a.size==2 ? a.first.product(a.last) :a.shift.product(recurse a)).map(&:join)
end

doit(["ABC", "DEF", "GHI"])  
  #=> ["ADG", "ADH", "ADI", "AEG", "AEH", "AEI", "AFG", "AFH", "AFI",
  #    "BDG", "BDH", "BDI", "BEG", "BEH", "BEI", "BFG", "BFH", "BFI",
  #    "CDG", "CDH", "CDI", "CEG", "CEH", "CEI", "CFG", "CFH", "CFI"] 

doit(["ABC", "DE", "FGHI"])
  #=> ["ADF", "ADG", "ADH", "ADI", "AEF", "AEG", "AEH", "AEI",
  #    "BDF", "BDG", "BDH", "BDI", "BEF", "BEG", "BEH", "BEI",
  #    "CDF", "CDG", "CDH", "CDI", "CEF", "CEG", "CEH", "CEI"]
```

Comment: I think you mean “non-destructive”.

Comment: (But, of course, since `map` is non-destructive the `dup` isn’t needed `:)`)

Comment: -2 for me, Andrew, but -1 for you, for not seeing that the first time.

Comment: You are giving -1 to yourself .. so bold you are.. :p

Comment: +1 Looks good although I tried with a long word and got `doit(["MUMMIFICATION"])  
SystemStackError: stack level too deep`

Comment: @Michael, my understanding of the problem is that the array must contain at least two strings (`["MUMMIFICATION"]` has only one).  An exception could be raised at the beginning of `doit()` if `b.size < 2`.  Thanks for pointing that out.